# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied with pip installation

Tags: windows-7, permissions, python, pip

**I have asked this question on SO, but they suggested, the question is better suited for Superuser.**

I installed Python 2.7.9 on Windows 7. It is supposed to have pip built-in. However, during Python installation, pip setup failed. I tried to install pip using get-pip.py, but it also failed giving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\get-pip.py", line 17853, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\get-pip.py", line 145, in main
with open(pip_zip, "wb") as fp:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'c:\\users\\ali\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpe8llat\\pip.zip'
```

I searched previous answers for similar problems. They mostly refer to running cmd as administrator, which I did, but I still get the same error.
I discovered that when I try to open any file using python in write mode 'w', it fails giving me the same error. I suppose that's why pip couldn't be installed. I tried opening files in different directories, but each time it fails.
This is giving me a hard time. Can somebody help me know why python can't write files on my PC?!

Answer (score 1):

Exit all python related process and try again.
pip cannot delete files which is currently using.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that you are logged in with user "ali" and have write access to the folder c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\tmpe8llat\
2. Uninstall existing Python 2.7.9 files
3. Download and reinstall 2.7.9 files

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, but I already did all of that and still continuously getting the same error!

Comment: When you performed the install did you do it with the Ali user account or as an Administrator?

Comment: Ali is an administrator account.

Answer (score -1):

I found that this error does not prevent the installation to be successful.

The files pip can't delete are some temporary files I believe. I usually delete them by hand from time to time.